# QT/SQLITE- Weird symbol on database?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm wondering why I'm getting this weird symbol with a box encapsulating 3 0's in three corners and a 3 in the last corner when I view my table using SQLite manager. If I use QString, the hours will I still be able to manipulate the hours column as if it were integer values? Thanks

```
void FirstWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    FirstWindow conn;

    QString rowid,Activity,thehours;
    Activity=ui->lineEdit->text();
    rowid=3;
    thehours=1;

    conn.connOpen();
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("insert into datatable (row,activity,hours) values('"+rowid+"','"+Activity+"','"+thehours+"')");

    //if this is good
    if(qry.exec())
    {
        this->hide();//hiding current ui
        mainwindow = new MainWindow(this);
        mainwindow->show();


        conn.connClose(); //close after inserting another
    }
```

Comment: "QString rowid = 3;" Is it a QString or an int?

Comment: Apparently, it ends up as a string containing the character U+0003.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are your columns strings or integers?

I would check whether *ui->lineEdit->text()* is actually returning a number.

Secondly, set the correct column type for the data you expect to save/load (integer, string, real, etc). This way the QSQLite errors will be much more helpful.

Third, you should avoid concatenating strings to prepare a sql query (imagine if *rowid* contains a **'** character!). The best way is just invoking prepare with sqlite placeholders, then add the values:

```
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("insert into datatable (row,activity,hours) values(?, ?, ?");
qry.addBindValue(rowid);
qry.addBindValue(Activity);
qry.addBindValue(thehours);

if(!qry.exec())
{
    qDebug() << qry.lastError();
}
```